# How does user variable pass to home view template

Tags: python, django

I currently following a tutorial at https://wsvincent.com/django-allauth-tutorial-custom-user-model/

I look at how they implemented home view.

### pages/views.py

```
# pages/views.py
from django.views.generic import TemplateView


class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'
```

### templates/home.html

```
<!-- templates/home.html -->
<h1>Django Login Mega-Tutorial</h1>
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<p>Hi {{ user.username }}
<p><a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log out</a></p>
{% else %}
<p><a href="{% url 'signup' %}">Sign Up</a></p>
<p><a href="{% url 'login' %}">Log In </a></p>
{% endif %}
```

However, I don't see how `user` variable is being passed to the home view template (`templates/home.html`). May I know how that happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have the default template `CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` in your settings module, one of which includes [django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/api/#django-contrib-auth-context-processors-auth) which sets the `user` variable in all of your templates.

Also, you can look at the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/context_processors.py#L61).